# Well known problem about irreducibles

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, polynomials, field-theory, finite-fields

I think this is well known, but I can't find a proof anywhere. Any help is appreciated.

> If $f(x)$ is monic and irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ with degree $m$, then $f(x)\mid x^{p^m}-x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints: suppose that $f(x)$ has degree $m$, and let $\alpha$ be a root of $f(x)$.

- What is $[\mathbb{F}_{p}(\alpha):\mathbb{F}_{p}]$? (this denotes the dimension of $\mathbb{F}_{p}(\alpha)$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$) In more explicit terms, how many elements does $\mathbb{F}_{p}(\alpha)$ have?
- Recall that any two finite fields of the same size are isomorphic.
- What is true about every element of the field $\mathbb{F}_{p^{m}}$? Can you think of a polynomial for which every element of $\mathbb{F}_{p^{m}}$ is a root?
- Finally, since $f(x)$ is the minimal polynomial for $\alpha$ (it is monic and irreducible and has $\alpha$ as a root), and the minimal polynomial must divide any other polynomial which has $\alpha$ as a root, what must be true?

(Note that by following this logic with a slight variation at the second step, you prove a stronger statement: that if $f(x)$ is monic and irreducible of degree $n|m$, then $f(x)|x^{p^{m}}-x$. Instead, you note that $\mathbb{F}_{p}(\alpha) \cong \mathbb{F}_{p^{n}} \subset \mathbb{F}_{p^{m}}$, and the rest follows.)

Comment: If possible could you state this in more elementary terms? I'm not too well versed with abstract algebra notation such as $\left[\mathbb{F}_p[\alpha]:\mathbb{F}_p\right]$

Comment: Certainly. Hang tight for a moment, I'll do my best to update the post!

Comment: @user114743, hopefully this clears some things up. Please let me know if you need any more clarification or have any more questions!

Comment: any finite extension of $F_p$ is a vector space over $F_p$ of ddimension $n$ for some $n \gt 1$ thus it has $p^n$ elements.

Comment: one of these is zero, so the multiplicative group of the extension field has order $p^n - 1$. by elementary group theory any element of the group has order dividing the order of the group. thus any non-zero element of the field, $ x $ must satisfy $x^{p^n-1} =1$. and the roots of this equation account for all non-zero elements of the extension.

Answer (score 6):

If you consider the quotient ring $K:=\Bbb F_p[x]/(f)$, this is a *field extension* of $\Bbb F_p$ of degree $m$.

Each element $\alpha$ of a degree $m$ extension of $\Bbb F_p$ satisfies $\alpha^{p^m}=\alpha$.

In other words, $x^{p^m}-x$ is $0$ in $K$, but that means that $x^{p^m}-x\,\in\,(f)$.